# Update Text Widget of a window from another window

Tags: tkinter

I am creating an tkinter application, and wish to add a new window to that app, where I can update the status of current operation. My intention is, every time, when an event is complete, I want to update that to a text widget of a separate window which runs in parallel. Similar to a console window, easy for users to read and understand the status of application/errors etc.

I am fairly new to python and Tkinter, my approach is as follows,

Before directly including it in the actual application, i tried to replicate what I had in mind, in a separate project.

First I have created a simple main Window as follows,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from Console import ConsoleWindow

class Main:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Main')
        self.master.geometry('640x480')
        self.btn = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'Run Console', command = self.runConsole)
        self.btn.pack(side = LEFT)
        self.btn2 = ttk.Button(self.master, text = 'Update Console', command = self.updateConsole, state = DISABLED)
        self.btn2.pack(side = RIGHT)

    def runConsole(self):

        self.btn.configure(state = 'disabled')
        self.btn2.configure(state = 'normal')
        consolewindow = Toplevel(self.master)
        console = ConsoleWindow(consolewindow)
        consolewindow.mainloop()


    def updateConsole(self):

        string = 'Console Text !!'
        ConsoleWindow.insertText(string)

def main():

    mainWindow = Tk()
    mainGUI = Main(mainWindow)
    mainWindow.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Next, a Console window

```
from tkinter import *

class ConsoleWindow:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.title('Console Window')
        self.master.geometry('640x480')
        self.scrollBar = Scrollbar(self.master)
        self.textArea = Text(self.master)
        self.scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.textArea.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        self.scrollBar.config(command=self.textArea.yview)
        self.textArea.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollBar.set)
        self.textArea.insert(INSERT, 'Running')
        self.textArea.configure(state='disabled')

    def insertText(self, textToUpdate):

        text = f'{textToUpdate}\n'
        self.textArea.configure(state='normal')
        self.textArea.insert(INSERT, text)
        self.textArea.configure(state='disabled')
```

What I expect to do is, to use the insertText function to update the Text Widget multiple times during the application runtime. When I run this code, I am able to create an instance of the ConsoleWindow, but when i press "update console" button, I get the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aswin Kumar\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Aswin Kumar/Console Window/Main.py", line 31, in updateConsole
    ConsoleWindow.insertText(string)
TypeError: insertText() missing 1 required positional argument: 'textToUpdate'
```

I tried adding ,the instance of ConsoleWindow to the insertText(),

```
ConsoleWindow.insertText(console, string)
```

And Getting the following error,

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aswin Kumar\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Aswin Kumar/Console Window/Main.py", line 31, in updateConsole
    ConsoleWindow.insertText(console, string)
NameError: name 'console' is not defined
```

How do I update the console window from my main window. Or is there any alternate approach which I can use for this case.

Comment: You're calling `insertText()` on the *class itself*, rather than the instance of the class that you've created.

Comment: Hey jason, Thanks. And yes, that worked, the problem was, the instance of the ConsoleWindow i created was not part of Main, or was only within the runConsole function, when i associated it withmain window, self.console = ConsoleWindow(consolewindow). Now this self allowed me to use the instance to call its function. Thanks.